# client.on() do not trigger

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am writing a discord boot, and I would like that if any person on the server gets the role, the boot will respond, but does not want to respond at all, did I write something wrong? Thank you

My code:

```
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", async (oldMember, newMember) => {
    if(newMember.roles.cache.has('830824982916366425')){
        fs.appendFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\pack\\output.txt", "Má suba", () => {});
        return;
    }
    else {
        fs.appendFile("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\pack\\output.txt", "NeMá suba", () => {});
        return;
    }
})
```

Comment: Why do you use async there? is there any purpose? Did you try to console.log part with checking newMember.roles.cashe.has() to see if it has it?

Comment: I needed as soon as possible. But i do not know how async works exactly.

Comment: You can remove async there, it is not needed

Comment: I removed it, but still not working. I go to dsicord change role and wait for output, but nothing. Did i do something wrong ?

Comment: after first line do console.log(newMember.roles.cache) and see what is the output in the console, does it even work? By the way do you have any errors there? in the console?

Comment: Yes i tried this, nothing happend and there is no errors in console.

Comment: I works, it was in setting on discord page

Comment: I suppose it was the intents. Look more about intents.